# CAS delegate authentication to Azure SAML

Tags: cas

I have been unsuccessful in getting Azure to be the IDP for my CAS server.

I used https://apereo.github.io/2019/02/25/cas61-delegate-authn-saml2-idp/ as a starting point.

Here is a snippet from cas.properties

```
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].keystorePassword=XXXX
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].privateKeyPassword=XXXX
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].keystorePath=/etc/cas/config/samlKeystore.jks
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].serviceProviderEntityId=https://MYHOST:8443/cas
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].serviceProviderMetadataPath=/etc/cas/config/sp-metadata.xml
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].identityProviderMetadataPath=https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX/federationmetadata.xml
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].clientName=SAML2Client
cas.authn.pac4j.saml[0].destinationBinding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST
```

These are the errors I am getting

If I login to my azure portal and run a test on my Enterprise Application I setup to work with CAS I get: Application Not Authorized to Use CAS

If I go to my CAS login page and use the Azure link to login I get: There was an XML error in the SAML message at line 2, position 758. Verify that the XML content of the SAML messages conforms to the SAML protocol specifications

Am I missing another setting that's needed in my cas.properties?
Do I need to create a json file in my services directory?  If so does some have an example of that?  Not sure how to find the error in XML file as none of the lines are that long in either sp or idp metadata.

Comment: Update the question per the CAS documentation:

Always ensure you have enough diagnostics data in your report:

- Have you reported the exact CAS version numbers that exhibit the seemingly-faulty behavior?
- Have you included error logs, debug logs, screenshots and other useful snippets of your configuration to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: version 5.3.11
From cas.log. 
2020-12-28 14:30:36,893 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.web.DelegatedClientWebflowManager] - <Delegated client identifier cannot be located in the authentication request [https://auth2-dev.oswego.edu:8443/cas/login?client_name=SAML2Client]>
2020-12-28 14:30:36,894 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.DelegatedClientAuthenticationAction] - <>